Persist dark mode in Nuxt 3
I use useDark from VueUse to implement the dark mode. When I go to another route the dark mode doesn't persist, possibly due to SSR, since the server doesn't know about the current mode.
I tried to solve the issue by using useCookie to store the mode in cookie, but it doesn't seem to work:
const darkModeCookie = useCookie("dark-mode", {
  path: "/",
  sameSite: "lax",
});

const isDark = useDark({ disableTransition: false });
const toggleDark = useToggle(isDark, () => {
  darkModeCookie.value = isDark.value ? "true" : "false";
});

if (darkModeCookie.value === true) {
  isDark.value = true;
} else {
  isDark.value = false;
}

I'm looking for a possible solution.

You can use the window.localStorage or useStorage provided by VueUse to store the user's preference and apply the preferred theme on the initial page load.

In SSR, the initial rendering happens on the server, which doesn't have access to the localStorage API. It might not work properly.
